# Laravel 5.2 - Upload image with ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel-5

I'm trying to upload an image with ajax like this:

**ROUTE**

```
Route::get('upload', 'PostController@addPhoto');
```

**VIEW**

```
<form action="" id="upload" enctype="multipart/form-data">                                         

<input type="file" id="file" name="file">

<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{csrf_token()}}" id="token">

<a href="#" class="btn-primary" id="submit">Upload</a>

</form>
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
public function addPhoto(Request $request){

        $file =  $request->file('file');
        //dd($file);
        return response()->json(['file'=>$file]);
}
```

**JS**

```
function upload(){

var token = $('#token').val();
var route =  "http://localhost:8000/upload";
var form = $('#upload')[0];
var formData = new FormData(form);

console.log(form);

     $.ajax({
      url: route,
      headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': token},                          
      type: "GET",
      cache: false,
      dataType:'json',
      processData: false,
      contentType: false,
      data: {'file': formData},
      success:function(data){
      console.log(data);
       },
    });
}

var uploaded = document.querySelector('#submit').onclick= upload;
```

In my controller `dd($file);` return null. Please how can i fix this error? how can i get the file image well? Maybe some error in ajax or form? I would like upload file image, thank you for your help!

Comment: i tryed with action="{{ url('upload') }}" AND  dd($file) return again NULL.

Comment: If you check the console is there any relevant errors? If you put a break point on the controller does it hit that statement? You should be looking to see if things at this point are connected. Also one way to check is to manually hit that endpoint and see if you can hit http://localhost:8000/upload